# How to classify a given number using cut operation in prolog

Tags: prolog

In my assignment,I am asked to write the simple prolog program using **cut operation**. Here I want to classify a given number either into integer class or real class.

Answer (score 0):

```
classify(N, integer) :-
    integer(N),
    !.

classify(N, real) :-
    float(N),
    !.
```

Assuming it's an exercise in cutting choicepoints rather than arguing how closely `float` describes reals.